# how to get notified whenever a client sends a complete object to a server in c#?

Tags: c#, networking, .net-core, server, networkstream

i am looking for a better way to create a simple server in c#

i already created one and its working fine , but it consumes a lot of cpu , and i am looking for a better way to optimize it

i wrote the following :

```
    class server
    {
        Task[] Clients=new Task[5];
        int counter=0;
        public void open(IPAddress addr,int port){

            TcpListener listener =new TcpListener(addr,port);
            listener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client =listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Clients[counter] = new Task(()=>handle_client_connection(client));
                Clients[counter].Start();
                counter++;   
            }
        }

        public void handle_client_connection(TcpClient client){
            System.Console.WriteLine("accpeted a new request");
            NetworkStream stream=client.GetStream();
            while(true){
            if(stream.CanRead){
            StreamReader reader =new StreamReader(stream);    
            string s=reader.ReadLine();     

            if(s != null){   
             System.Console.WriteLine("message recieved :"+s);
            }
            }
           }
        }

    }
```

the `while` loop inside the `handle_client_connecion()` method is what is bothering me the most 
i am wondering if there is a way to know if the client has sent any data to the network stream and get notified whenever he does so

the client keeps serializing a simple object and sending it as a `string` multiple times ,and i don't know the time when the client sends their message , i don't want to get stuck in a while loop and keep checking whether its empty buffer or not ,i also am worried if i end up reading only half of the message 
from the client , please help !

Comment: Use “framing” to know when a logical packet/object is sent. For example, send an object serialized as compact JSON - then every line is guaranteed to contain a complete object.

Comment: The loop should end when ReadLine returns null (see the documentation). However, since ReadLine *blocks* it won’t be a hot-busy loop. The StreamReader should be created *once* and used repeatedly in the loop.

Comment: Then as long as it’s set to emit *compact* (aka non-formatted) output it will work by reading a line at a time. This is because JSON strings can never contain raw newline characters.

Comment: no the client keeps sending messages multiple times , thats why i have a loop, im also using newtonsof.json to serialize and deserialize objects , i dont know how to use framing !!

Comment: Line-by-line is a form of framing (identifying different logical payloads). See the documentation for the return of ReadLine and CanRead. Make sure to _exit_ the loop when appropriate.

Comment: okey ,i will ,thanks , but i still have the problem of staying in a loop to verify whether the client has sent a new object or not !!

Comment: i cant exit the loop forever , the client will always send objects at different times

Comment: Frankly, writing good network servers is **really really hard**. It would take almost no effort to use a pre-rolled tool such as gRPC, which does all the hard work for you. Any reason to no just use something like that?

Comment: If ReadLine returns a non-null value then there is a new object (the line). ReadLine will wait (block) until a complete line is ready. This is why emitting JSON _without formatting_ is key to this approach. When null is returned, end the loop - the connection was closed. Remove CanRead entirely, as it doesn’t mean data is available.

Comment: As for how to fix the server: async socket IO with a zero length read would be a good way, but: that's quite a long way from this code

Comment: i cant use anything else , its for educational reasons , plus thank you so much , you helped me understand how Readline works !!

Comment: Exit the loop. Honest. The loop is only for a single connection / client. New tasks are created so there is a loop running per connection / client. Have fun.

Comment: no i cant do that , i must be conected to different clients , ithink Marc has answered the question , the keys is in async sockets  as the reading operation will block until there is a full object to read from and it will return whenever it has read it completly , i just googled it and it sounds perfect , i just have to test it now , thanks guys

Comment: @ezio emphasis: async IO is **not trivial**; doing this *badly* is easy, but doing it *well* is a significant amount of work - again, I strongly recommend using pre-rolled tools for this, unless you really want to take the time to learn this area in depth. I have a multi-part blog series covering much of it...

Comment: can you please give me the link to your blog , i really want to learn this area in depth !!

Comment: @MarcGravell can you please show me examples of tools to help implementing servers , i read about grpc and it looks like its for remote procedure calls , but i only want message passing , im doing this because im trying to implment a p2p network and  remote procedure calls can be dangerous i guess !! please help :(

Comment: @ezio 3-and-a-bit saga starts here: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html - the later sections are more code centric

Comment: @ezio note: I can pretty much guarantee you that anything pre-rolled (like gRPC) is going to be at least one order of magnitude - maybe two - less dangerous than something you write yourself

Comment: @MarcGravell but grpc is for remote procedure calls , can i safely implement remote procedure calls in a p2p network where nodes can be malicious (byzantine)  !! also your blog is amazing

Comment: @ezio gRPC doesn't allow arbitrary code execution; services are explicitly declared, and only the things you have chosen to expose are surfaced - with the tools running the exact code your *server* (not the client) wants to run; that... sounds ideal, no?

Comment: @MarcGravell sorry for the late comment ,and  i get it now thanks to you  , but can i for example implement it in a mobile network , the server needs to be minimalistic , i dont want to add too much overhead ,well because :its mobile ,does grpc consumes lots of ressources is the right question , and again thank you so much for taking the time to answer my questions